# Upload a photo to facebook using Corona?

Tags: lua, facebook

Is is possible to upload a photo to facebook using Corona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just posted a [sample](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/facebook) that does exactly this.

Comment: The link is now dead: "You don't have permission to access /content/facebook on this server."